# AVPlayer video frozen yet audio is playing

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avkit

Hi could anyone please help me with the following. In my UIViewContoller I have a tableView and one instance of AVPlayer that receives the different url per cell for playing and embedded as subview in the tableViewCell. And I need to implement full-screen mode option for playing video on taping on the button in tableViewCell. In this method I use something like this:

```
   myVideoPlayer.stopPlaying
   let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
   playerViewController.player = myVideoPlayer
   self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
    playerViewController.player.play()
   }
```

The actual result is: AVPlayerViewController is opened the video is playing from the relevant time but after 3-4 seconds it stops rendering yet audio continues playing. And if I close this controller in my cell audio is playing from the relevant time that was the last from the controller but the video is frozen.

Comment: can you share the complete code snippet of how you are initializing `myVideoPlayer` ?